# Using Pyglet to scale gif to screen

Tags: python, gif, pyglet

Anyone can bring some clarity to my code as to why when I attempt to scale my gif to full screen half the screen is white while the other is the gif(animation)? This is using the Pyglet python module.

Here's my code along with an image of the issue:

````py
'Load animation'
animation = pyglet.image.load_animation('Goober#13427G.gif')
animSprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(animation)

# 'Scale image to screen *harcoded*'
# animSprite.scale_x = 3.2
# animSprite.scale_y = 1.71

' Get display and create a fullscreen window while scaling gif to screen'
display = pyglet.canvas.Display()
screen = display.get_screens()

H_ratio = max(animSprite.height, screen[1].height) / min(animSprite.height, screen[1].height)
W_ratio = max(animSprite.width, screen[1].width) / min(animSprite.width, screen[1].width)

animSprite.scale = min(H_ratio, W_ratio) 

window = pyglet.window.Window(width=screen[1].width, height=screen[1].height, fullscreen=True, screen=screen[1])

r, g, b, alpha = 1, 1, 1, .5
pyglet.gl.glClearColor(r, g, b, alpha)


@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    animSprite.draw()


pyglet.app.run()
```[Gif with second half of screen to the right is white][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsbJy.jpg
````

Comment: Hello ! The gif is supposed to have the same format as the screen ? (16/9) 
Do you expect the gif to be stretched to the screen format  or cut to the top/bottom ?

Comment: I'm expecting the gif to stretch according to the monitor size, say im using a 27" monitor it should proportion accordingly. I've tried putting the monitor I am using to display the gif on portrait mode but it would cause the same issue where half the screen is white.

Answer (score 1):

Try scaling each axis.

```
animSprite.scale_x = W_ratio
animSprite.scale_y = H_ratio
```

Comment: I tried this snippet above and while it worked, it did create some distortion and currently am deciding to just leave a aspect ratio that's appropriate rather than the corner to corner full screen stretch of the animation instead.

Comment: You will have to scale the ratio based on the image rather than the window and then position and scale it based on the Window. It might be simpler to just use a combination of fixed resolution.Check out this example: https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet/blob/pyglet-1.5-maintenance/examples/fixed_resolution.py

Comment: That seems like it may be the answer I've been looking for! a lot more in depth of what I actually thought it'd but im trying to figure where I would actually load my animation into it now and replace the actual rectangle animation given

Comment: Essentially you would replace the `rectangle.draw()` with the drawing of your sprite/blitting image/whichever.

Comment: I did, but it comes distorted still or cut off. Have been trying to figure out how the implications are done but I figured to replace `rectangle.draw( )` and with my animation and while it does replace it, it comes out very out of proportion